# plotting data from a dat file in R

Tags: r, plot

I am reading a manual of R that contains the following data in a file:

```
0.319132782  0.808869293
0.612725533  0.932766104
0.205770354  0.695866667
0.395410972  1.044069042
0.449560874  0.932377679
0.532886257  1.009741399
```

data is delimited by a couple of blank spaces between each number. It is a .dat file
In one part of the example the author wants to plot the data and puts:

```
plot(all.x,all.y,xlab="x",ylab="y")
```

I have read the file with:

```
all<-read.table("examples.dat",header=F)
```

for the references to all.x and all.y I use

```
all.x<-all[1]
all.y<-all[2]
```

the problem is that when I plot I got an error of stripchart, why is that?

Comment: "*the problem is that when I plot I got an error of stripchart*" -- do you have a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always refer to a column in a data frame using its colID. See below:

`plot(all[,1],all[,2],xlab="x",ylab="y")`